# How to substitute variables into Python format string

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a Python string like such:

```
template = '{a} or {b} but not {c}; {d} and {e}, not {f}'
```

Later, variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` are defined. They are not defined before `template` is, so I cannot use an f-string literal. I want to substitute their values into `template`.

This could be achieved by using the `.format()` string method:

```
template.format(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f)
```

However, I am looking for a more compact way of expressing this.

Using `**kwargs` with `globals()` works if the variables are global:

```
template.format(**globals())
```

However, I am looking for something that works for locals or globals — something concise, which effectively produces the same result as using an f-string literal like:

```
template = f'{a} or {b} but not {c}; {d} and {e}, not {f}'
```

Again, an f-string does not work in this case because the letter variables are not defined yet when `template` is defined.

Thank you!

Comment: [Why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) do you want to do this, exactly?

Comment: [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352): I want to have some form of template (like a format string) such that I can substitute into that template variables which it references by their names, repeat this as those variables change, and get the string output.

Comment: Is the only problem with `template.format(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f)` that it isn't compact enough?

Comment: [mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651): That solution (a=a, b=b, ...) works, but my actual code uses many more variables which all have to be substituted in, so I am looking for a less lengthy solution that has the same effect.

Comment: maybe you can write your code such that all of the relevant variables are stored in some context dict rather than as actual variables so you can use `template.format(**ctx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals). At the module level, `locals()` and `globals()` are the same dictionary.

Update : If some variables are in global and some of them are in local you can Union them using new `|` operator:

```py
template = '{a} or {b} but not {c}; {d} and {e}, not {f}'

a = 10;b = 20;c = 30;d = 40

def fn():
    e = 50;f = 60;h = 70
    print(template.format(**globals() | locals()))
    
fn()
```

or

```py
def fn():
    print(template.format(**{**globals(), **locals()}))
```

The local dictionary will override values in global dictionary.

Comment: This doesn't work in the case that some of the letter variables are locals and some are globals.

Comment: @tol Check the update please.

Comment: This works, but I was hoping to find a solution which was less of a workaround — something which effectively did the same thing as an f-string (which I think this does) without having to use `globals()`/`locals()` or `eval()` like the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can kind of recreate the f-string in this way:

```
result = eval("f'{}'".format(template))
```

Just use this after all the variables are defined. This is basically a more convenient way to do `template.format(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f)`

Comment: More convenient, and also more dangerous. Folks will forget `eval` is buried in the code and it winds up accepting user input at some point... whoops. It's just another thing to document and keep in mind; better to just avoid `eval` and be explicit.

Comment: This works (and indeed simulates an f-string literal), but I was looking for a solution which would avoid workarounds, especially dangerous ones such as `eval()`.